# Hibernate @ManyToMany association table with extra field that can be queried differently

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I was trying to do @ManyToMany association and it worked when I tried to do relations like

User can have multiple group and one group can multiple user.. it worked ,and hibernate created custom table based on it automatically and it did its worked. later **I had to add more columns to the association table** so I followed a article and set the things up as per that, which worked pretty good.

I am using SpringBoot and is using SpringDataJPA

Here is my implementation :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<UserGroup>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<UserGroup>();
     
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_GROUPS")
public class UserGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")  
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Group group;
     
    // additional fields
    private boolean activated;
    private Date registeredDate;
 }


User user = new User("tommy", "ymmot", "tommy@gmail.com");
Group group = new Group("Coders");

User persistedUser = userRepository.save(user);
Group persistedGroup = groupRepositry.save(group);
 
UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup();
userGroup.setGroup(persistedGroup);
userGroup.setUser(persistedUser);
userGroup.setActivated(true);
userGroup.setRegisteredDate(new Date());
 
userGroupRepository.save(userGroup);
```

> Now how to write a SpringData equavalent methd name for getting user's
> group where the user is active ? i.e I make user active = false when
> some one deletes users from a group instead of deleting the entry from
> the user_group assossiation table.
>
> Can we do it on the userRepository?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would like to have repository similar to this one:

```
public interface UserGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<UserGroup, Long> {

    List<UserGroup> findAllByUserAndActivatedIsTrue(User user);

}
```

This method will give you List of all groups that this user is assigned to and is active.
If you would like to parameterize also activated field, you should instead use
    `List<UserGroup> findAllByUserAndActivated(User user, boolean activated);`

I hope that this helps you. Good luck.

And btw, I recommend reading this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods
Helps a lot